# Ubuntu Boot loader option not coming

Tags: 14.04, bios

I recently performed a BIOS update on my Windows 10 (HP machine). Now whenever I start my PC, the boot loader option for Ubuntu doesn't show up on the screen. Rather, the system directly starts Windows 10. What should I do? Should I reinstall Ubuntu on my PC?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Boot section in your BIOS, it is very possible after the BIOS upgrade, your settings are reset. If you were using UEFI boot for grub, change back to UEFI mode, and set it to use the grub bootloader.

If you were using legacy boot and it changed to UEFI boot, enable CSM and set the first boot disk to the drive ubuntu is installed on.